# comparing the time taken by mathematical operations

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, math, operation

Which implementation whould be faster (in theory)-

```
long int total=0;
for(int n=1;n<=200000;)`
{ 
  total=total + n*(++n);
}
```

or

```
 long int total=0,sum=0;
for(int n=1;n<=200000;n++)`
{ 
  sum =sum+2*n;
  total=total + sum;
}
```

Or will there not be any difference?

Comment: It depends!  There's not nearly enough information here.  What language are you using?  What architecture?  What compilation options (assuming that you're using a compiled language)?  What's the magnitude of `n`?  What's the *type* of `n`? Are the successive calls all together, or is there other code going on in between?  And a thousand other questions ...  There's really no good possible answer here except "Time it and see."

Comment: I would suggest to put this question in different forum. If you are trying to achieve this via some programming then please mention the programming language. Else you can try to post this here. http://math.stackexchange.com/

You may get faster responses in that community.

Comment: for this particular problem i am using C, and 1≤n≤2×10^5. Its part of a for loop which computes only this result and nothing else

Comment: If `n==1` they do not even have the same answer!

Comment: @chux Thanks for noticing that . I  had made a mistake in calculation. Its corrected that now + had to re-frame the question .I hope this one is more clear

Comment: The post is questionable: It ask which is faster: A) "sum = n*(n+1)" "for each n with initial value of sum=0" or B) "sum = sum + 2*(n)" "for each n with initial value of sum=0"?  Certainly the correct question is which is faster: C) "sum = n*(n+1)"  or D) `"sum = sum + 2*(n)" "for each n with initial value of sum=0"?  C does not iterate, but D does.  C is faster.

Comment: @both will be withing a for loop, i don't get what you mean by only one will iterate

Comment: Edit-made the code simpler and the whole block is code is written now ,sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is write explicitly the two programs you want to compare. I think I know what you mean, but it would be definitive if you wrote it explicitly.

Assuming my guess is right about what you mean, asymptotic time complexity makes no sense for this question, because there is no free variable. `n` is "bound" to the loop. If you replaced `200000` with `M` then it would make some sense to talk about time complexity.

The question of which of the two programs that you didn't write is faster in absolute terms is also a poorly framed question, because the answer most likely depends on context, as Mark Dickinson has pointed out. If my guess is right about what the programs look like, then the number of arithmetic operations seems to be roughly the same. That could mean the programs would run in about the same amount of time, or maybe not. My guess is the time difference would be imperceptible, but why don't you just try it?

Finally, if you're going to use the short cut `2(1)+2(2)+...+2(n)=n(n+1)`, then why don't you go further and use a short cut for the summation of `1(2)+2(3)+...+n(n+1)`? We have

```
n(n+1) = (1/3)((n+1)^3 - n^3) - (1/3)
```

so

```
1(2)+2(3)+...+n(n+1) 
= (1/3)(2^3-1^3) - (1/3) + (1/3)(3^3-2^3) - (1/3) + ... + (1/3)((n+1)^3-n^3) - (1/3)
= ((n+1)^3 - n - 1)/3
```

The series is "telescoping", so all the cubed terms in the middle cancel. The resulting expression can be evaluated in 5 arithmetic operations.

If you substitute n=200000 in the above, you'll see that `int total` will overflow for 32 bit `int` types. Is that your intent?

**Update**

I tried it on my system (MacBook Air/Yosemite). The programs I compared are

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  long int total;
  for (int trial=0; trial<1000; ++trial) {
    total = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<=200000; ++i) {
      total = total + i*(i+1);
    }
  }
  printf("answer is %ld", total);
  return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  long int total;
  int sum;
  for (int trial=0; trial<1000; ++trial) {
    total = 0;
    sum = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<=200000; ++i) {
      sum = sum + 2*i;
      total = total + sum;
    }
  }
  printf("answer is %ld", total);
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled both with `gcc -O` and then ran them under the unix `time` command. The clear winner (on my system, with its particular architecture, and with the choices I made) is the first program. It takes about 160 milliseconds, whereas the second takes about 240 milliseconds. The first runs in 2/3 the time of the second. I don't know enough about the architecture to speculate on the reason for the difference.

Note that the line in your program `total = total + i*(i++);` is incorrect. That calculates `i*i` then increments `i`. Furthermore, both that line and the improved `total = total + i*(++i)` generate a warning.

A few stylistic issues: I use `i` rather than `n` for a loop index, so people don't get confused about what `n` means. I habitually use `++x` to increment x rather than `x++` which may make an unnecessary temporary copy of the old `x`.

Comment: i guess you are right about writing the whole program, it thought it would be easier to read if i keep it short,in the original problem i used long int. All this time I can't help but think that it would more time to multiply two large numbers and less time to add something to the previously calculated sum.Am i wrong with that ?

Answer (score -2):

Well, if you are talking in terms of algorithm then complexity for first operation is higher than the second one. 
Complexity for first operation is O(1) where as in second case it will be O(n).
So when your number of inputs increases, then probably first one will take less time than second one.
Delay is directly proportional to machine instructions required to execute the operation.

Comment: Sorry, but this is nonsense.  Where do you get the idea that computing `n * (n+1)` has complexity `O(n^2)` from?

Comment: As written, the first one is O(1), and the second is O(n).

Comment: I agree. It is a mistake from my end. for the first one it will be o(1). I might have assumed details but thanks for correcting me.

Comment: It's better, but still wrong. The question states that the second method depends on the previous computations. It's just one step, not n steps, so it still isn't an O(n) operation.

Comment: okay. what does this mean then, sum = sum + 2*(n+1) for each n ? As there is no additional information, you should understand that intention is to loop for each n and do this one statement execution. If you are assuming something, do let me know. I will be happy to understand.

Comment: It was explained in the original question: "the second one has 3 operations (two additions and one multiplication) but uses some already calculated value in previous step." It's one step, not all n.

Comment: Is that going to make any difference as long as we are looping for all values of n - probably large value of inputs? If it is going to perform 3 operations, we can ignore the constants right? Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. The task is to calculate the value of sum n times. You can use the direct formula n times, or you can use the incremental update n times. Do not compare doing everything with doing one step. Compare doing one step vs one step. Which is faster?